# Stack of UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, stack

I am creating a stack of `UIView` objects.

I need to have a `UIView` at the center of a `UIViewController` that will have swipe gestures. Based on the swipe direction, it will move out of screen using an animation.

Under it I will have the same view.

Now I am planning how to do it.

As you can see here, I use only 2 `UIView` objects: top and bottom.

Then check that `UIView` is on top now and then assign new frame to it and assign next data to bottom view. Ok, it's not hard.

But maybe there is more easy way to do it? `UIScrollView`? `UICollectionView`? child view controllers? Or anything else?

Comment: Not sure I totally understand the problem, but if they are just swiping on and off screen, two child UIPageViewControllers might save you a bunch of time.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9372097/77567)?

Comment: You could also, prior to the animation process, add a UIImageView as subview, where you can add a snapshot of the previous view, add a temporary new UIView to be added in the animation. When animation completes, remove the UIImageView from its superview, and assign the temporary view to your self.view.